# Can my IT admin see websites I hit via VPN

Tags: vpn

I have access to a VPN network while I'm in my office. If I'm in the VPN I can access sites that my office network has blocked. Can the IT admins see that I'm going to those sites? And if so at what part of the network is it visible?

Comment: For sure they can see that you're using a VPN. On another note, you might consider asking this at https://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Yeah the VPN is allowed. It allows me to support a customer.

Comment: So the VPN server is in the customer, is it? You can access said sites because the customer's network doesn't block them, correct?

Comment: Yes. When on the con network I'm connected to the customers network and the internet blockage is different. Not the same site are blocked.

Comment: By reading wikipedia, it looks like there are several ways to implement VPN, some of which your IT admins would be able to see what you do. So maybe it would be nice if you could find out which implementation is being used by your customer's server. That could give you some details and clues on how much privacy you're getting on your vpn. Good luck! :)

Comment: When I connect to specific VPNs, I have it configured so all traffic on that client goes thru the encrypted VPN tunnel and routes from there. In this case, what I do is not possible for another network admin to see unless they check local web browser history from the machine I'm using. I would agree that it depends tho...